# how to split a string into several blocks of characters?

Tags: android, string, split

I have a string that came from an array called `fld[1].tostring`. When i try and split this string which returns `"|R1|R2|R3"` on the | it splits it into each character. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The split method accepts regular expressions. The pipe character is used to denote a logical *or* in Java regular expressions. Escape the character with a backslash to split on it.

For example:

```
String s = "|R1|R2|R3";
String[] a = s.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you very very much! i needed a double \\ but you got me there!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I was a little bit too quick on the trigger I guess ;).

Comment: |R1||R3|| getting fail in this case

Answer (score 2):

`Vertical bar "|"` is special character. and `String.split()` need a regualar expression.
try escaping it and treating it as special char:

```
fld[1].split("\\|");
```